Losing a settlement permit in Berlin, Germany
If someone lost their permanent residence card a.k.a Niederlassungserlaubnis, were they able to get it renewed through an appointment at Bürgeramt with the following category:

Niederlassungserlaubnis oder Erlaubnis zum Daueraufenthalt-EU auf
einen neuen Pass übertragen
Transfer settlement permit or EU permanent residence permit to a new
passport

I lost mine a couple of weeks back, and I have submitted a message via the contact form at LEA, with a police report attached, but I didn't hear anything from them. I have booked an appointment online, but I'm unsure if that's the right one.
I couldn't find any category for a lost item.


If someone lost their permanent residence card a.k.a Niederlassungserlaubnis, were they able to get it renewed through an appointment at Bürgeramt ...

Doubtfull, since the Bürgeramt does not issue the Electronic residence title (eAT) in the first place. They also will not have your (immigration) personal data that would be required to issue a new card.

I lost mine a couple of weeks back, and I have submitted a message via the contact form at LEA ...

Landesamt für Einwanderung (LEA) is the Immigration Office (not the Bürgeramt), so your appointment is probably at the Immigration Office at the Friedrich-Krause-Ufer.

I have booked an appointment online, but I'm unsure if that's the right one. I couldn't find any category for a lost item.

You have already reported the card as lost. So it is a matter of  getting a new card.
So you have made the correct appointment at the right place.

Sources:

Electronic residence title (eAT) – Loss or theft - Service-Portal Berlin



Inform the Berlin Immigration Office about the loss or theft of your eAT (in writing, by e-mail, phone or personally).

New electronic residence title
You need to have your residence document renewed. Please make an appointment for a transfer of the data (see section “More information”).

